# Overwrite hyperlink style in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, hyperlink

I use Bootstrap for my CSS style. I would like to fake a link as button, so I need to turn off hover styling:

```
a:hover {
         color: #00438a;
         text-decoration: underline;
```

}

How would I override hover properties in my html file (and not overwriting what has been defined in Bootstrap).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the style for a specific id tag.

So change:

```
a:hover {
     color: #00438a;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

to

```
a#some_id_tag_name:hover {
     color: #00438a;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Or create a specific class that overrides if you want to reuse the style.

```
a.some_class_tag_name:hover {
     color: #00438a;
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually "turn off" CSS styles, you can only explicitly set them to something else (the `inherit` value being *somewhat* of an exception). Anyways, in your case:

- Add a `class` to your link
- Create a new rule for it in your stylesheet
- Define your styles

Something like:

```
.my-class:hover {
      color: {YOUR_COLOR};
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

You could also use inline style and `!important` if you really, really have to:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none !important"></a>
```

Avoid the second method whenever possible (i.e. almost always).